# Tailwind CSS IntelliSense for monaco-editor

Tags: tailwind-css, monaco-editor

I'm looking for some help: I want to add TailwindCSS IntelliSense / suggestions into Monaco Editor. There is an official extension for VSCode https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss - but unfortunately, I know it's impossible to add VScode plugins into Monaco.

Another Website ( https://play.tailwindcss.com/ ) uses the same IntelliSense with Monaco Editor.

Thanks

[image: Tailwind CSS IntelliSense VScode Extension]

Answer (score 2):

Remcohaszing  realeased a package for Tailwindcss intellisense support in Monaco editor :

https://github.com/remcohaszing/monaco-tailwindcss